# Binary Numbers Magic Trick

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity, matrix

The challenge is simply; output the following six 2D integer arrays:

```
[[ 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51],
 [ 3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53],
 [ 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55],
 [ 7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57],
 [ 9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59]]

[[ 2, 11, 22, 31, 42, 51],
 [ 3, 14, 23, 34, 43, 54],
 [ 6, 15, 26, 35, 46, 55],
 [ 7, 18, 27, 38, 47, 58],
 [10, 19, 30, 39, 50, 59]]

[[ 4, 13, 22, 31, 44, 53],
 [ 5, 14, 23, 36, 45, 54],
 [ 6, 15, 28, 37, 46, 55],
 [ 7, 20, 29, 38, 47, 60],
 [12, 21, 30, 39, 52]]

[[ 8, 13, 26, 31, 44, 57],
 [ 9, 14, 27, 40, 45, 58],
 [10, 15, 28, 41, 46, 59],
 [11, 24, 29, 42, 47, 60],
 [12, 25, 30, 43, 56]]

[[16, 21, 26, 31, 52, 57],
 [17, 22, 27, 48, 53, 58],
 [18, 23, 28, 49, 54, 59],
 [19, 24, 29, 50, 55, 60],
 [20, 25, 30, 51, 56]]

[[32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57],
 [33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 58],
 [34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59],
 [35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60],
 [36, 41, 46, 51, 56]]
```

What are these 2D integer arrays? These are the numbers used in a magic trick with cards containing these numbers:

[image]

The magic trick asks someone to think of a number in the range [1, 60], and give the one performing the magic trick all the cards which contain this number. The one performing the magic trick can then sum the top-left numbers (all a power of 2) of the given cards to get to the number the person was thinking of. [Some additional explanation of why this works can be found here.](http://www.mathmaniacs.org/lessons/01-binary/Magic_Trick/)

### Challenge rules:

- You can output the six 2D integer arrays in any reasonable format. Can be printed with delimiters; can be a 3D integer array containing the six 2D integer arrays; can be a string-list of lines; etc.
- You are allowed to fill the bottom right position of the last four cards with a negative value in the range `[-60, -1]` or character `'*'` instead of leaving it out to make the 2D integer arrays rectangular matrices (no, you are not allowed to fill them with `0` or a non-integer like `null`/`undefined` as alternative, with the exception of `*` since a star is also used in the actual cards).
- The order of the numbers in the matrices is mandatory. Although it doesn't matter for the physical magic trick, I see this challenge mainly as a [matrix](/questions/tagged/matrix)-[kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) one, hence the restriction on order.
  The order of the matrices themselves in the output list can be in any order, since it's clear from the top-left card which matrix is which.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139138/binary-magic-cards) (As in, it's referring to the same magic trick, but not really useful to get inspiration from for this challenge I think. That challenge asks to output a truthy/falsey value whether number `n` appears on the `k`'th card; where my challenge is a KC-challenge to output the six matrices.)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Hm, I'm not so sure if this is really a duplicate, because your challenge is [tag:ascii-art] (not tagged as such, but it is), while this one allows you to output the array in a way more lenient format (not just four essentially identical ways). I can't vote to reopen, though, because I have a hammer.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Woops.. Forgot I have a hammer as well >.> Sometimes being able to close/open hammer is pretty annoying.. It had 2 votes already though, so with yours and mine in addition there were 4 open votes. But if someone wants to close it again I don't mind. They are indeed very similar, although his challenge is indeed an `[ascii-art]` challenge with strict (MD5) output rules, where mine are very flexible (and the rows/columns are swapped, and range is `[1,60]` instead of `[1,63]`; pretty minor differences, but still).

Comment: Looks like you didn't try to VTRO with an attitude of "this is my precious challenge!!!" at least... :P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No, that was indeed not my intention. :) If I knew about his challenge I probably wouldn't have posted mine in the Sandbox. But since it's already here I can see your earlier point, and I indeed see quite a bit of differences (although also just as many similarities) between the two challenges. If I would be like "my previous challenge :(" I would had already opened it as soon as the close-vote came in. ;P But I could understand it. Now that I'm remembered my vote is a hammer I'll leave it to others to open-vote it next time..

Comment: I too forgot about the hammer.  I still think this is close enough to vote to dup, though I'll defer to the wisdom of the community if it is reopened.

Comment: Not related to the challenge, but to the magic trick: other versions of those cards scramble the numbers (with the power of two in some convenient spot) so that how it works is less obvious. Unfortunately, this makes it a little more likely the chooser will miss a card, so the magician may want to have some patter ready in case that happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

-1 byte thanks to the master himself:)

```
60:B"@fQ6eq
```

Explanation:

```
60:           % create a vector [1,2,3,...,60]
   B          % convert to binary matrix (each row corresponds to one number)
    "         % loop over the columns and execute following commands:
     @f       % "find" all the nonzero entries and list their indices
       Q      % increment everything
        6e    % reshape and pad with a zero at the end
          q   % decrement (reverts the increment and makes a -1 out of the zero
              % close loop (]) implicitly
              % display the entries implicitly
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38zAyknJIS3QLLXw/38A)

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>63</s> 46 bytes

```perl6
say grep(*+&2**$_,^61)[$_,*+5...*for ^5]for ^6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhvSi1QENLW81IS0slXifOzFAzGkhraZvq6elppeUXKcSZxoIpoHoA)

Outputs as 2D arrays on multiple lines, with the last array of each one cut off if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 76 bytes

```python
r=range;print[[[i for i in r(61)if i&2**k][j::5]for j in r(5)]for k in r(6)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8i2KDEvPdW6oCgzryQ6OjpTIS2/SCFTITNPoUjDzFAzM00hU81ISys7NjrLyso0FiSbBZE11QTzsqFqNWP//wcA)

The method here is to create a list of all possible numbers `r(61)` and then whittle that down to the list of numbers for a card `i&2**k`.

Then, by using list slicing, that 1D list of numbers is rearranged to the correct 6x5 card size `[card nums][j::5]for j in r(5)`.

Then, this generator is just repeated for 6 cards `for k in r(6)`.

---

While I could not find any solutions less than 76 bytes, here are two others that are also 76 bytes:

```python
r=range;print[[[i for i in r(61)if i&1<<k][j::5]for j in r(5)]for k in r(6)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8i2KDEvPdW6oCgzryQ6OjpTIS2/SCFTITNPoUjDzFAzM00hU83QxiY7NjrLyso0FiSbBZE11QTzsqFqNWP//wcA)

This next one is inspired by [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184867/81432).

```python
k=32
while k:print[[i for i in range(61)if i&k][j::5]for j in range(5)];k/=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9vW2IirPCMzJ1Uh26qgKDOvJDo6UyEtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcPMUDMzTSFTLTs2OsvKyjQWJJ2FkDbVjLXO1rcFmgYA)

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｅ⁶Ｅ⁵⪫Ｅ⁶§⁺§⪪Φ⁶¹＆πＸ²ι⁵ν⟦*⟧λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYkxC8IwEEb/ypHpIueg0C5OdRAqCAFHcQhtwIMjCWm0/vt4Dh0ej@9908uXKXlpzRWOFW8@Y0/wV0dwTRy3NNQxzuGLTt4LbuOehSteWGoo2B8IzlxXXsIQZ8wELq3ajwRsrSXolKg8zM481aIYMPrZU2tt/5Ef) Link is to verbose version of code. I tried calculating the entries directly but this was already 27 bytes before adjusting for the `*` in the bottom right. Outputs each row joined with spaces and a blank line between cards. Explanation:

```
Ｅ⁶                          Loop over 6 cards
  Ｅ⁵                        Loop over 5 rows
     Ｅ⁶                     Loop over 6 columns
           Φ⁶¹              Filter over 0..60 where
               π            Current value
              ＆             Bitwise And
                 ²          Literal 2
                Ｘ           Raised to power
                  ι         Card index
          ⪪        ⁵        Split into groups of 5
         §          ν       Indexed by column
        ⁺                   Concatenated with
                      *     Literal string `*`
                     ⟦ ⟧    Wrapped in an array
       §                λ   Indexed by row
    ⪫                       Joined with spaces
                            Implicitly print
```

Comment: I added that rule about `*` for fun after I saw the stars on the actual cards. Was wondering if there would be any languages using it, but I'm glad to see at least one did. :) Nice answer!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Charcoal doesn't have a transpose operator, and the golfiest transpose requires a rectangular array of known size, so I need to add something to make up the size, and `*` is at least as short as anything else would be.

Comment: I don't think this is 26 bytes...

Comment: @Tvde1 Charcoal, like many of the esolangs on this site, uses a custom code page. Characters from that page cost 1 byte, while other characters cost up to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
60L2вíƶ0ζε0K5ô®ζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//zYwTDLQssOtxrYwzrbOtTBLNcO0wq7Otv//)

**Explanation**

```
60L                 # push [1 ... 60]
   2в               # convert each to a list of binary digits
     í              # reverse each
      ƶ             # multiply each by its 1-based index
       0ζ           # transpose with 0 as filler
         ε          # apply to each list
          0K        # remove zeroes
            5ô      # split into groups of 5
              ®ζ    # zip using -1 as filler
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
6F60ÝNoôāÈÏ˜5ô®ζ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//zZGNjDDnU5vw7TEgcOIw4/LnDXDtMKuzrYs//8)

**Explanation**

```
6F                  # for N in [0 ... 5] do
  60Ý               # push [0 ... 60]
     Noô            # split into groups of 2^N numbers
        āÈÏ         # keep every other group
           ˜        # flatten
            5ô      # split into groups of 5
              ®ζ    # transpose with -1 as filler
                ,   # print
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>82</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 74 bytes

```python
i=1 
exec"print zip(*zip(*[(n for n in range(61)+[-1]if n&i)]*5));i*=2;"*6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWUIErtSI1WamgKDOvRKEqs0BDC0xEa@QppOUXKeQpZOYpFCXmpadqmBlqakfrGsZmpinkqWVqxmqZampaZ2rZGlkraZn9/w8A)

<sub>-4 bytes, thanks to Jonathan Allan</sub>

Comment: Nice. The `iter` keyword is redundant here since [a generator will do the job just as well](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWUIErtSI1WamgKDOvRKEqs0BDC0xEa@QppOUXKeQpZOYpFCXmpadqmBlqakfrGsZmpinkqWVqxmqZampaZ2rZGlkraZn9/w8A).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Cool, thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
ṠMöTC5Wnünḣ60
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBb6Ht4U4m4bnHd6T93DHYjOD//8B)

### Explanation

```
          ḣ60  Range [1..60]
        ü      Uniquify using equality predicate
         n     bitwise AND: [1,2,4,8,16,32]
 M             For each number x in this list,
Ṡ     W        take the indices of elements of [1..60]
       n       that have nonzero bitwise AND with x,
    C5         cut that list into chunks of length 5
  öT           and transpose it.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
6Æ60õ f&2pX)ó5
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVE&code=NsY2MPUgZiYycFgp8zU)

```
6Æ              Create a range from 0 to 5 (inclusive) and map each X into
  60õ             Elements in the range [1..60]
      f             Where
       &2pX)          The number bitwise AND with X is not 0
  ó5              Split into 5 arrays, where each array contains every 5th element

-Q flag is just for formatting purposes
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 95 bytes

```c
i,j,k;f(int o[][5][6]){for(i=6;i;)for(o[--i][4][5]=j=k=-1;j<60;)++j&1<<i?o[i][++k%5][k/5]=j:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NboMwEIX3nMJylMqWISVRYNGx1YO4XlRQkrETXFGyijg7sSFV89O3Gs18M@9Nle2qalxgWx1O9RehP32NfrWnI6Y2ddAwbHvitdGF0aXh58Z3DFUJCDyWXmcZGr2Nc2WVU9karCxz4ELYl7WU@O51AIRwy3DBvUbsLYdhPH5iy/g5IUGTx6kPBrMNTN2GhR6/1r4jUxRUORCUJRAhkJN5/46wkbCyiIS9Je4oFyk333GPVNR3F7CG0eWmJjSd4oU/bPjBXDP9akj@2/to6Q33xzzPh2RIxgs)

Returns the matrices as a 3D int array in o.

The last 4 matrices have -1 as their last value.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

Saved <s>7</s> 8 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing `o[i][4][5]=-1;for(j=k=0;` to `for(o[i][4][5]=-1,j=k=0;` so the brackets can be removed. Nice answer btw, +1 from me.

Comment: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY9NboMwEIX3nMJylMqWISVRYNGx1YO4XlRQkrETXFGyijg7sSFV89O3Gs18M@9Nle2qalxgWx1O9RehP32NfrWnI6Y2ddAwbHvitdGF0aXh58Z3DFUJCDyWXmcZGr2Nc2WVU9karCxz4ELYl7WU@O51AIRwy3DBvUbsLYdhPH5iy/g5IUGTx6kPBrMNTN2GhR6/1r4jUxRUORCUJRAhkJN5/46wkbCyiIS9Je4oFyk333GPVNR3F7CG0eWmJjSd4oU/bPjBXDP9akj@2/to6Q33xzzPh2RIxgs)

Comment: (Note that I'm not 100% sure if passing a 3D array already allocated with the correct dimensions is allowed. But I'll let regular C golfers provide a better insight about that.)

Comment: @Arnauld I was thinking about that, but decided against it.

Comment: better to leave out `#include` to show that it works without it

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>90</s>  88 bytes

```javascript
_=>[1,2,4,8,16,32].map(n=>(g=i=>i<60?g(++i,i&n?m[y%5]=[...m[y++%5]||[],i]:0):m)(y=m=[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjhCoIwFEDhpynu2G2olYR054OMEcN0XHGbZASC777273xndj@3DR9ev5eY3mOeKL9ImxobvOED6xavjVXBrRBJgycmzc@26j1Iycjn2Aezn@6WjFKqpJQFx2Essu0q0QUBOwUyVog8pLilZVRL8jBBGX8)

#### Commented

```javascript
_ =>                        // anonymous function taking no argument
  [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]      // list of powers of 2, from 2**0 to 2**5
  .map(n =>                 // for each entry n in this list:
    ( g = i =>              //   g = recursive function taking a counter i
      i < 60 ?              //     if i is less than 60:
        g(                  //       recursive call:
          ++i,              //         increment i
          i & n ?           //         if a bitwise AND between i and n is non-zero:
            m[y % 5] =      //           update m[y % 5]:
            [ ...m[y++ % 5] //             prepend all previous values; increment y
              || [],        //             or prepend nothing if it was undefined so far
              i             //             append i
            ]               //           end of update
          :                 //         else:
            0               //           do nothing
        )                   //       end of recursive call
      :                     //     else:
        m                   //       return m[]
    )(y = m = [])           //   initial call to g with i = y = m = []
                            //   (i and y being coerced to 0)
  )                         // end of map()
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

Inspiration taken from both [TFeld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184861/53748) and [The Matt's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184865/53748).

```python
k=32
while k:print zip(*zip(*[(i for i in range(61)+[-1]if i&k)]*5));k/=2
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9vW2IirPCMzJ1Uh26qgKDOvRKEqs0BDC0xEa2QqpOUXKWQqZOYpFCXmpadqmBlqakfrGsZmpilkqmVrxmqZampaZ@vbAo0CAA)**

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 88 bytes

```
Transpose@Partition[#~Append~-1,5]&/@Last@Reap[Sow[,NumberExpand[,2]]~Do~{,60},Except@0]
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a TIO link (based on _@J42161217_'s answer). +1 from me.

Comment: 91 bytes?: [`Transpose@Partition[#~Append~-1,5]&/@Last@Reap[Do[Sow[k,k~NumberExpand~2],{k,60}],Except@0]`](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsIwEADQXykITpFWQTfhBLuJFHULGc561BCSHMmJBTG/Hn3z8yhP8ih2xDrt6y1hyBwzwYBJrNgY9KIcmCk8ymqttmbZwgmzwIWQ9THqa3xrp1w5v/ydUj8z/ufGqI9Tu@5rVD@PxAKdqUOyQZoWmqnWHw)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks.  I've used this `~` trick in one more place and replaced the variable `k` by `Null`.  Sorry, no time to add a tio link.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
60&ƇⱮs€5LÐṂZ€
```

A niladic Link which yields a list of (6) lists of lists of integers. (It outputs the using the default option of having no `*` or negative filler.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/MQO1Y@6ON64ofNa0x9Tk84eHOpigg8/9/AA)**

#### How?

Each matrix contains, in column-major order, the numbers up to \$60\$ which share the single set-bit with the top-left (minimal) number.

This program first makes ***all*** \$60\$ possible ordered lists of numbers in \$[1,60]\$ which share ***any*** set-bit(s) with their index number. It then splits each into chunks of \$5\$ and keeps only those with minimal length - which will be the ones where the index has only a single set-bit (and hence also being its minimal value). Finally it transposes each to put them into column-major order.

```
60&ƇⱮs€5LÐṂZ€ - Link: no arguments
60            - set the left argument to 60
    Ɱ         - map across ([1..60]) with:  (i.e. [f(60,x) for x in [1..60]])
   Ƈ          -   filter keep if:  (N.B. 0 is falsey, while non-zeros are truthy)
  &           -     bitwise AND
      €       - for each:
     s 5      -   split into chunks of five
         ÐṂ   - keep those with minimal:
        L     -   length
           Z€ - transpose each
```

---

Lots of 15s without realising the "minimal by length when split into fives" trick:

```
5Ż2*Ɱ60&ƇⱮs€5Z€
6µ’2*60&Ƈ)s€5Z€
60&ƇⱮ`LÞḣ6s€5Z€
```

...and, while attempting to find shorter, I got another 13 without needing the trick at all:

```
60B€Uz0Ts5ZƊ€
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (18 bytes)

```
6{61{2A#&},5/zp}fA
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=6%7B61%7B2A%23%26%7D%2C5%2Fzp%7DfA). This is a full program which outputs to stdout.

#### Dissection

```
6{             }fA    # for A = 0 to 5
  61{2A#&},           #   filter [0,61) by whether bit 2^A is set
           5/z        #   break into chunks of 5 and transpose to get 5 lists
              p       #   print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 99 bytes

```
Transpose@Partition[#~FromDigits~2&/@Last@GatherBy[{0,1}~Tuples~6,#[[-k]]&],5]~Table~{k,6}/. 61->-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvBCsIgGADgVxEGO2lmkLdCIurSYQdv4uEvxGSbDv07xJivbvTdvxnw7WbA8ILmT01niGVJxakBMgYMKZqu3nKar8EHLPXQc/WAgur@j/nyNeueiq3qzzK5UiXtjGGjtb2lR1s1PCdX15HKje@IFOzMRBtyiEi4Ir61Hw)

Comment: You can save a few char by: doing `Transpose@` instead of `Transpose[...]`; padding to 30 entries before partitioning; using `Table[...,{k,6}]` to avoid needing `k=#`.

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch Table may save one byte. Did you try transpose@? Because it doesn't work if you watch carefully. I'm afk but will golf later

Comment: Sorry, `Transpose@` works after you move `PadRight` inside `Partition`.  Another comment is that the question does not seem to allow `""` for the placeholder; you can replace it by `-1` without losing any byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
60B€Uz0µTs5Z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/MwOlR05rQKoNDW0OKTaM0//8HAA)

Loosely based on [flawr’s MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184878/42248). A niladic link which outputs a list of lists as required.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 73 bytes

```r
`!`=as.raw;lapply(0:5,function(i)matrix(c((a=1:60)[(!a&!2^i)>0],-1),5,6))
```

I am not entirely sure if I have met the requirement for order, since R by default fills matrices by column, so the order such that it appears physically on the cards is the same as the way matrices are allocated in R.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0ExwTaxWK8osdw6J7GgIKdSw8DKVCetNC@5JDM/TyNTMzexpCizQiNZQyPR1tDKzEAzWkMxUU3RKC5T084gVkfXUFPHVMdMU/P/fwA)

Comment: The output looks good. And if R fills matrices by columns before row instead of row before column like almost all other languages, it just means it's a good programming language to use for this challenge I guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, (<strike>1,168</strike> 1,139 bytes)

I just wanted to know I could do it.

**Optimised version**

```
 WITH g AS(SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM g WHERE n+1<61),B as(SELECT cast(cast(n&32 as bit)as CHAR(1))+cast(cast(n&16 as bit)as CHAR(1))+cast(cast(n&8 as bit)as CHAR(1))+cast(cast(n&4 as bit)as CHAR(1))+cast(cast(n&2 as bit)as CHAR(1))+cast(cast(n&1 as bit)as CHAR(1))as b FROM g),P as(SELECT * from (values(1), (2), (4), (8), (16), (32)) as Q(p)),S as(select distinct p,p+(substring(b,6,1)*1)*(case when p=1 then 0 else 1 end)+(substring(b,5,1)*2)*(case when p=2 then 0 else 1 end)+(substring(b,4,1)*4)*(case when p=4 then 0 else 1 end)+(substring(b,3,1)*8)*(case when p=8 then 0 else 1 end)+(substring(b,2,1)*16)*(case when p=16 then 0 else 1 end)+(substring(b,1,1)*32)*(case when p=32 then 0 else 1 end)as e from P cross apply B),D as(select * from S where e>=p and e<61),R as(select p,(row_number()over(partition by p order by cast(e as int)))%5 as r,e from D),H as(select k.p,'['+stuff((select','+cast(l.e as varchar)from R l where l.p=k.p and l.r=k.r for xml path('')),1,1,'')+']'as s from R k group by k.p,k.r)select stuff((select','+cast(x.s as varchar)from H x where x.p=z.p for xml path('')),1,1,'')from H z group by z.p
```

**Online demo**

[Try it online!](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1905/1)

**Verbose version - with notes as SQL comments**

```
WITH gen -- numbers 1 to 60
AS (
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=60
),
BINARIES -- string representations of binaries 000001 through 111111
as (
SELECT 
    +cast( cast(num & 32 as bit) as CHAR(1))
    +cast( cast(num & 16 as bit)  as CHAR(1))
    +cast( cast(num & 8 as bit)  as CHAR(1))
    +cast( cast(num & 4 as bit)  as CHAR(1))
    +cast( cast(num & 2 as bit)   as CHAR(1))
    +cast(cast(num & 1 as bit)  as CHAR(1)) as binry FROM gen
),
POWERS -- first 6 powers of 2
as (
SELECT * from (values(1), (2), (4), (8), (16), (32)) as Q(powr)
),
SETELEMENTS -- cross apply the six powers of 2 against the binaries
-- returns 2 cols. col 1 = the power of 2 in question.
-- col 2 is calculated as that power of 2 plus the sum of each power of 2 other than the current row's power value, 
-- but only where a given power of 2 is switched "on" in the binary string, 
-- ie. where the first digit in the string represents 32, the second represents 16 and so on. 
-- That is, if the binary is 100100 then the number will be 
-- the sum of (32 x 1) + (16 x 0) + (8 x 0) + (4 x 1) + (2 x 0) + (1 x 0) 
-- but if the current row's power is 32 or 4, then just that number (32 or 4) is excluded from the sum.
-- rows are distinct.
as (
select distinct powr,
powr+
 (substring(binry,6,1) * 1) * (case when powr = 1 then 0 else 1 end)
 +(substring(binry,5,1) * 2) * (case when powr = 2 then 0 else 1 end)
 +(substring(binry,4,1) * 4) * (case when powr = 4 then 0 else 1 end)
 +(substring(binry,3,1) * 8) * (case when powr = 8 then 0 else 1 end)
 +(substring(binry,2,1) * 16) * (case when powr = 16 then 0 else 1 end)
 +(substring(binry,1,1) * 32) * (case when powr = 32 then 0 else 1 end) as elt
from POWERS cross apply BINARIES
),
DISTINCTELEMENTS -- purge calculated numbers smaller than the power of 2 or greater than 60
as (
select * from SETELEMENTS where elt >= powr and elt < 61
)--,
,
ROWNUMBERED -- for each power, number the rows repeatedly from 0 through 5, then back to 0 through 5 again, etc
as (
select powr, (row_number() over (partition by powr order by cast(elt as int)))%5 as r, elt  from DISTINCTELEMENTS
),
GROUPEDSETS -- for each row number, within each power, aggregate the numbers as a comma-delimited list and wrap in square brackets - the inner arrays
as (
select r1.powr, '['+stuff((select ',' + cast(r2.elt as varchar) from ROWNUMBERED r2 where r2.powr = r1.powr and r2.r = r1.r for xml path('')),1,1,'')+']' as s
from ROWNUMBERED r1
group by r1.powr,r1.r
)
select -- now aggregate all the inner arrays per power
stuff((select ',' + cast(g2.s as varchar) from GROUPEDSETS g2 where g2.powr = g1.powr for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from GROUPEDSETS g1
group by g1.powr
```

**Voila!**

Note 1: Some of the logic pertains to rendering square brackets and commas.

Note 2: Newer versions of SQLServer have more compact approaches to creating comma-delimited lists. (This was created on SQL Server 2016.)

Note 3: Arrays for a given card are not sorted (which is ok per the spec). Numbers within an array are correctly sorted. In this case, each "card" of the question, renders its arrays on a separate row in the results.

**Shorter to hard-code arrays?**

Yes.

Byte me.

Comment: Jeez, wouldn't it be shorter to just hardcode the result?

Comment: Haha. Neither as fun, nor extensible.

Comment: I do not fully understand -- are you saying that your solution only works by chance or are you convinced you followed the specifications correctly?

Comment: @JonathanFrech - I did not explicitly code for the ordering of the numbers, although there may be an implicit condition in the language resulting in a guaranteed order. They render in correct ascending order. Separately, after posting, I realised I had misunderstood how the data were to be presented (in striped arrays per card, rather than one single set per card) - so have yet to solve that problem. As such, the result currently renders the correct numbers, in ascending order, within each of the 6 expected sets - see the linked sql fiddle. Still to do: break the sets into 5 subsets each.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but if your solution is not correct, please fix it or delete your post. We generally do not allow for invalid answers to linger.

Comment: @JonathanFrech fixed.

Comment: :| "viola" is a musical instrument

Comment: It'll be violins soon 

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```
v←∊+\¨n,¨29⍴¨1↓¨(n⍴¨1),¨1+n←2*0,⍳5⋄((v=61)/v)←¯1⋄1 3 2⍉6 6 5⍴v
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/6XAZmPOrq0Yw6tyNM5tMLI8lHvlkMrDB@1TT60QiMPwtEEShhq5wFVGmkZ6Dzq3Wz6qLtFQ6PM1sxQU79MEyh@aL0hUMhQwVjB6FFvp5mCmYIpUGvZf6AV/9MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 112 bytes

```cs
_=>" ".Select(x=>Enumerable.Range(1,60).Where(l=>(l&x)>0).Select((a,b)=>new{a,b}).GroupBy(i=>i.b%5,i=>i.a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NS8QwEIZRPNie/AkhqGQgBhX0spscBBXFkx72uKRhuhuJU0lbbbf0t9coonvZOT0z7wfj6jNX@@muJTevild0jXy4pfYNoy0Cznexp8akKfW01Ibv7R8cHjGuXjCkAtFp829Vz5ZWKC7k9TmoxRojiqCNCKcdmHT5jQgrC9CG8HNINIK6j1X7ftMLr41XxcmV/AELMM3ysopo3Vp82Mg2zBMrBbUhALAhz7bF/lvcQJ5li@gbfPKEom6ip5V6rDwJLhmX/d/bTBt2zIdOXo4cAGb5Vixt4/QF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>108</s> 107 bytes

```
n: 32 until[b: collect[repeat k 60[if n and k = n[keep k]]]loop 5[print
extract b 5 b: next b]1 > n: n / 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc07CsMwEEXRPqt4O4hjYxeGZBFphyn0mYCQGAkxAe9eVnmae7vE8ZVIPPTEtuKvlgr5E6GWIsGoSxNnyDgWSj8onMapN5SySENm5lJrw06tJ7WHXNZdMHjsmB2dhucXPpgHxRMrj3ED)

Answer (score 1):

**MATLAB, 155 bytes**

```
cellfun(@disp,cellfun(@(x)x-repmat(62,5,6).*(x>60),cellfun(@(x)reshape(find(x,30),[5 6]),mat2cell(dec2bin(1:62)-48,62,ones(1,6)),'Uniform',0),'Uniform',0))
```

This could be shorter as multiple lines but I wanted to do it in one line of code.

Comment: Could you perhaps add [a TIO link](https://tio.run/#) with test code, so I can verify the output?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
žOε60LDNo&ĀÏ5ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D7/c1vNDHxc/PLVjjQc7jc9t/P/fwA)

Comment: Why the `žO` instead of just `6L`? I know you're not using them in your map, but I'm curious why you've used `aeiouy` to create a list with 6 values. xD Nice answer, btw!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No particular reason, I just thought it was funnier than `6L`, `6и`, `5Ý`, `5°`, or `9!`.

Comment: It certainly caught my eye, that's for sure. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I just realized `тœ`, `₅œ`, `₁œ`,  also work, those are pretty cool too (:

Comment: `₆b` would work as well ;)